# Update array of objects with Parse javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I  am trying to update an object in Parse which has an array of other objects as one of its properties.

E.g. There is a parent type 'Type1' and it has an array property "childTypes", which stores 'Type2' objects.

If I query Type1 from server and then save it back, it works, but I'd like to update some fields of Type2 instances after the query, rearrange them inside the array and THEN save Type1 back.

I receive error **"Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject"**, but I checked and Type1 object has its id, also all Type2 instances have their ids. They are Parse.Object objects.

I am trying to save like this:

```
var oldChildTypes = type1.get("childTypes");
// rearrange childtypes here ...

var childTypes = [];
childTypes.push(...) // push rearranged Type2 items one by one

type1.set("childTypes", childTypes);
type1.save(...);
```

**I have already tried:**

1. Saving just empty array `type1.set("childTypes", [])` - it works.
   but as soon as I add one of Type2 objects to it - same error, although these Type2 objects are taken from the very same type1 object's "childTypes" array.
2. Also there is a very strange case - if I convert Type1 object to string with JSON.stringify, it produces correct result, but this invokation `JSON.stringify(type1.get("childTypes"))` gives exactly the same error about unsaved ParseObject. I have no idea how stringify is connected with Parse.Object. Probably parse overrides something.

Maybe there is a different way of setting array in Javascript SDK? I could not find it in the API. This name of 'Parse' makes it so hard to google anything :( especially with the word 'json'.

Here is the source of [ParseObject](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/37f433152031cdb5c782d12fbcead2c97c49e0cf/src/ParseObject.js) here and this error is produced when an object does not have id property. There is only one object in my hierarchy without an id and it is an array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are just fine :|
Just another bug caused adding other object in the hierarchy and it was not visible in console logs.

Although it's interesting why this error is breaking JSON.stringify